# compiling QT source results in QMAKE unknown errors

Tags: qt5, qmake

I am doing this on SLES 11.4 which does not have QT5, and has qmake 4.6.3 and gcc-4.3.4

`./configure` initially failed and I remedied that by using a locally built gcc-7.2.0.  It then succeeded.

When running `qmake` I receive this

```
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:2:  Unknown test function: cache
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:10: Unknown test function: for
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:33: Unknown test function: for
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:48: Unknown replace function: sort_depends
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:49: Unknown replace function: reverse
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:50: Unknown test function: for
WARNING: /qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8/qt.pro:95: Unable to find file for inclusion qt_configure
```

What does that mean and is there a means of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

To build Qt itself you never run `qmake` on the source tree.
If configure already succeeded, run `make`.

It looks like you're running the `qmake` that comes with your system. That one doesn't support several features used by Qt's project files.

Comment: thanks.  it told me after `configure` specifically to `just run qmake` followed by `qmake install`.  I was pretty sure before i asked the correct solution is to upgrade to sles 12 which has qt5... trying to run software that needs qt5.

Comment: It tells you to run make, not qmake:

`Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into....`

Comment: i need glasses.  it actually says `just run gmake`